# C# gridview set focus to next cell automatically

Tags: c#

I am writing a Winforms application where user can enter hex values in gridview but only upto FF in one cell. I want to let user enter long values without pressing enter or tab, if user types FFFF the value should go to two cells of gridview. I am trying to set focus to next cell automatically, by counting 2 keys like below.

My code is not working I am not sure if my approch is correct. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
private void hexGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(CheckKey);
}

private void CheckKey(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.KeyChar = char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar);
    char c = e.KeyChar;

    if (!((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') || validForAll.Contains((Keys)e.KeyChar)))
    {
            e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
            if (++count > 2) // or something same
            {
                count = 0; 

                int r = hexGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                int ci = hexGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                ++r; //just for testing 
                hexGridView1.CurrentCell = hexGridView1[r, ci];
                hexGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
                hexGridView1.BeginEdit(true); //require ?
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code have fix my issue insted of using Count use function.

```
            if(hexGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString().Length == 2)
            {
                int iColumn = hexGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int iRow = hexGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (iColumn == hexGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
                {
                    if (hexGridView1.RowCount > (iRow + 1))
                    {
                        hexGridView1.CurrentCell = hexGridView1[0, iRow + 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //focus next control
                    }
                }
                else
                    hexGridView1.CurrentCell = hexGridView1[iColumn + 1, iRow];
            }
```